# Clicking on programmatically added pictureBox controls

Tags: c#

I have a Winforms application where I programmatically add a number of pictureBox controls and load each one with an image.

How can I link each pictureBox control with a video file so I can run that video by clicking on that pictureBox control?

This is how I add my pictureBox controls:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file_address = ofd.FileName;
        }
var picture1 = new PictureBox

        {
            Name = "pictureBox",

            Size = new Size(160, 200),
            Location = new Point(x, y),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            Image = Image.FromFile(file_address),
        };
 this.Controls.Add(picture1);
```

I've managed to add click event handler:

```
 picture1.Click += delegate
    {
            // Do something 
    }
```

Comment: *"...as they all have the same name"*, there is your problem. You want the names to be unquie.

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyway to name each one with unique one?

Comment: You could do something like: `Name = "pictureBox" + i`, where `i` is an index from `1` to `n` for you list of picture boxes.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add the click event handler to it right away or keep a reference to the picture box instead of trying to find it by its name later? Show some more code (of adding the event handlers and such) and we can probably suggest something better.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Why can't you just put the code for opening `picture1`'s video in your event handler?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad because all pictureBox controls have the same  name how can I link each one with different  video file?

Comment: Post all of your code relevant to the videos and pictureboxes. I can't tell what you're doing wrong from what you have so far. I know for sure you shouldn't be trying to find the picture box by the name. I remember doing that when I first started developing with windows forms and it is a bad approach. It took a while for me to learn better ways. (dsum's posted answer provides one option for fixing this, there are potentially others)

Comment: I didn't write that part yet when I suck thinking that it can't be done as far as I wasn't able to know which pictureBox I clicked on where all have the same name!
now I changed it as  Spencer Wieczorek suggested and each one now has a unique name and I'll now try to link each one with video file and see, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Tag property to store the file_address.

```
this.picture1.tag = file_address;
```

when you want to play the video by the picture box file name, get the file name by

```
string file_name = (string)this.picture1.tag;
```

Comment: That worked for me, now I can click on each pictureBox and get different video file linked as needed, Thanks all.